# Prove that in a Euclidean domain $R$, if a condition is satisfied then $x$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain with function $h$ satisfying Deﬁnition 12.15.

> (a) Prove that $x$ is a unit of $R$ if and only if $h(x) = h(1)$.
>
> (b) Prove that if $x,y \in R$ are associates then $h(x) = h(y)$

Definition 12.15 says

> An integral domain $R$ is a Euclidean domain if there exists a function $h:R\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{Z}_{≥0}$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> (A) $h(xy) \ge h(x)$ for any $x,y \in R\setminus\{0\}$.
>
> (B) For any $x,y \in R\setminus\{0\}$ there exist $q,r \in R$ such that $y = qx + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $h(r) < h(x)$ ($r$ is the “remainder” of division of $y$ by $x$)

For a, I was able to get the forward direction, but I need help getting that $h(x)=h(1)$ implies $x$ is a unit.

I also can't get that $h(x)=h(y)$.  $x$ and $y$ are associates so $x=uy$ where $u$ is a unit, but I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 1):

By (a) $h(t)\ge  h(1)$ for all nonzero $t$. By (b) if $h(x)=h(1)$ there is $q$ with
$1-qx=0$ or $h(1-qx)<h(x)=h(1)$. The latter is impossible, so $qx=1$
and $x$ is a unit.

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$:

$\implies$.

If $x$ is a unit, then $qx =1$. So by the first condition $ h(x) \ge h(1)$. Also using theat condition again ( as $x =x,y= q$), then you have $ h(1) \ge h(x)  $Thus this implies $h(x) = h(1)$.

$\Longleftarrow$
Given $ h(x) = h(1)$. Using the second condition  $ 1 =xq +r $ we have $ h(r) <h(x)  =h(1)$. But thats a contradiction as by the first condition $ h(r) \ge h(1)$.

(b):

If $x$ and $y$ are associates ,so $x = uy$ and $ y= u^{-1}x$. where $u$ is a unit.
Thus now applying the first condition on both of them and using  $(a)$ of the question ($h(u)= h(u^{-1})= 1$),we have $h(x) \ge h(y)$ and $h(y) \ge h(x) \implies h(x) = h(y) $.